# The premise regarding demon, hole in the heart, and child

Tags: the-world-god-only-knows

It is stated in chapter 1 that the demons hide themselves in a human heart, and are kicked out once the hole in the heart is filled.

> [image: chapter 1]

However, in chapter 3, it is stated that they only hole themselves up in the hearts of women, because they will be born as the woman's child.

> [image: chapter 3]

But in the majority of cases, they'll find love at some point before the child is conceived, so the demon would already be kicked out. So what's the point of artificially banishing all of them beforehand with the MC?

Comment: Given some of the behavioral changes and other weirdness that happens in late-stage cases, I wouldn't be surprised if the implanted demons decided to take things into their own hands....

Comment: How can a premise devised by an author be flawed?  Translations can be somewhat flawed......but as the question is worded, no, I don't think the "premise" is flawed.

Comment: Like Clockwork-Muse says, as the darkness inside the host grows, the demon would get stronger and when they get stronger, they might put weird thoughts into the host, making them offering themselves to some random guy so they get impregnated and then the demon can get reborn. Or even worse, like in Kusunoki's case, the demon might control the host's body.